# Animating a Sphere to move along a 3D curve

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How do I get a sphere to move along a 3D function in Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Please give an example of the sort of "3D function" you want to use, preferably in *Mathematica* code.

Comment: The title says 3D curve, but the question body says 3D function (aka surface). Which do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Animate` and define your curve..

```
Animate[Graphics3D[Sphere[{Sin[t], Cos[3 t], 0}, .1], 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: And here I was thinking the 3D function was a surface `f[x, y, z] == 0`.

Comment: @Michael, why not? That's a lot more terrain to cover, tho.